# Python AsyncSSH

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Вообщем использую python библиотеку: [asyncssh](http://asyncssh.readthedocs.org/en/stable/#client-examples) для выполнения команд по ssh.
Вот код:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def run_client():
    conn, client = yield from asyncssh.connection("178.79.132.133", username="root", password="1234")
    with conn:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = yield from conn.open_session('echo "Hello!"')
        output = yield from stdout.read()
        print(output, end='')

        status = stdout.channel.get_exit_status()
        if status:
            print('Program exited with status %d' % status, file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print('Program exited successfully')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client())
```

Но к сожалению ничего не происходит и в консоль ничего не выводиться...

В консоли без проблем могу зайти:
`ssh root@178.79.132.133`
Потом ввожу пароль, все хорошо, а тут не работает, где ошибка? При помощи `paramiko` тоже все хорошо работало.

Вообщем дальше больше. Стал выеснять. К серверу, который на Ubuntu присоединяется, а вот на OpenSUSE почему-то не получается.

Стал смотреть логи соединения:

OpenSUSE (к которому получается присоединиться но не проходит авторизация):

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 178.79.133.135 [178.79.133.135] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA f2:1c:bc:f8:a5:ae:15:02:5d:a1:25:d2:e6:05:73:74
debug1: Host '178.79.133.135' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ivan/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Ubuntu к которому получилось присоедениться и пройти авторизация:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.24 [192.168.0.24] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ab:80:e4:3f:33:d3:06:cd:22:c8:c6:da:84:83:97:62
debug1: Host '192.168.0.24' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ivan/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ivan/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Скажите, что не так? Что нужно поправить в настройках сервера ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем выяснил. Оказывается у ssh есть несколько типов авторизации:
publickey,keyboard-interactive, password. Как я понял, когда мы используем консольный клиент, то используется (не рассматриваю вариант с ключами) keyboard-interactive, видимо `paramiko` как-то умеет эмулировать данный тип, а вот `asyncssh` нет, ну или я не разобрался как. Решение оказалось простым:

1. Через ключи
2. На сервере ssh поставить: `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Comment: Зачем разрешать пароли, если Вы ключи используете?

Comment: Пока тест, то и с паролями покатит.